# I am having problems passing a variable between classes in Python when stored inside of an __init__ function

Tags: python, customtkinter

As stated in the title, I have been having problems with passing over the variables from one section of code to another.

I have looked up potential solutions to this issue, however, I am either too inexperienced with python to implement them properly or too unlucky to have found the answer yet. The first part of the code is the `strength` class, of which I wish to grab the `self.strengthValue` variable and pass it over...

```py
class strength():
    def __init__(self):
        # create strength window
        strengthFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(coreFrame, corner_radius=0, width=340, height=60)
        strengthFrame.place(y=250, x=5)
        
        # strength attribute
            # Name
        self.strength = ctk.CTkLabel(master=strengthFrame, text="Strength", height=10, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=14, weight="bold"))
        self.strength.place(y=5, x=5)
            # Variable
        self.strengthValue = tk.IntVar()
        self.strengthValue.set(0)
            #Value
        self.strengthEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(justify="center", master=strengthFrame, width=40, height=10, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=12), textvariable=self.strengthValue)
        self.strengthEntry.place(y=5, x=295)
        self.strengthEntry.insert(0, 0) # Starting value
        
        # Skills
            # Strength
                # Athletics
        self.athletics = ctk.CTkLabel(master=strengthFrame, text="Athletics", height=10, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=14, weight="bold"))
        self.athletics.place(y=25, x=15)
                    # create the variables for the radio buttons and the entry field
        self.athleticsValues = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
        self.athleticsProfSelect = ctk.IntVar(value=0)

        # create the radio buttons
        for i in range(7):
            rb = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=strengthFrame, text="A", variable=self.athleticsProfSelect, value=self.athleticsValues[i])
            rb.place(x=5+i*35, y=40)
                
        # create the label to display the sum
        self.athleticsProfDisplay = ctk.CTkLabel(master=strengthFrame, text="0")
        self.athleticsProfDisplay.place(y=30, x=295)
        
        # set the function to be called whenever a radio button or the entry field changes
        self.athleticsProfSelect.trace("w", lambda *args: self.updateAthleticsSum())
        self.strengthValue.trace("w", lambda *args: self.updateAthleticsSum())
    
    # create a function to update the sum label whenever a radio button or the entry field changes
    def updateAthleticsSum(self):
        total = self.athleticsProfSelect.get() + self.strengthValue.get()
        self.athleticsProfDisplay.configure(text=str(total))
```

...the second part of the code is the `savingThrows` class where i wish to put the `self.strengthValue` variable into a sum in order to display it.

```py
class savingThrows():
    def __init__(self, strengthObject):
        self.strengthObject = strengthObject
    # create saving throws window
        self.savingThrows = ctk.CTkFrame(coreFrame, corner_radius=0, width=340, height=130)
        self.savingThrows.place(y=115, x=5)
    
        self.STTitle = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.savingThrows, text="Saving Throws", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=14, weight="bold")).place(y=0, x=5)
    
    # endurance
        self.endurance = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.savingThrows, text="Endurance", height=10, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=14, weight="bold"))
        self.endurance.place(y=25, x=15)
        self.enduranceProf = ctk.CTkComboBox(master=self.savingThrows, width=85, height=10, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=10), values=["Untrained", "Novice", "Apprentice", "Journeyman", "Expert", "Master", "Grandmaster"])
        self.enduranceProf.place(y=25, x=140)
        self.enduranceDisplay = ctk.CTkEntry(justify="center", master=self.savingThrows, width=40, height=10, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=10), placeholder_text="000")
        self.enduranceDisplay.place(y=25, x=295)
        # recalculate button
        self.recalculateButton = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.savingThrows, text="Recalculate", width=55, height=10, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=10), command=self.recalculateEndurance)
        self.recalculateButton.place(y=25, x=230)

    def recalculateEndurance(self):
        enduranceDict = {"Untrained": 0, "Novice": 1, "Apprentice": 2, "Journeyman": 3, "Expert": 4, "Master": 5, "Grandmaster": 6}
        selectedValue = self.enduranceProf.get()
        self.enduranceDisplay.delete(0, "end")
        self.enduranceDisplay.insert(0, str(enduranceDict[selectedValue] + strength.strengthValue.get()))
```

I am using the `tkinter`, `customtinkter` and `random` libraries and nothing else. I have cut away any code I did not think was relevant but am willing to provide it if necessary.

So far I have tried to pass over the `strength` class by using the normal methods of making an instance and placing it between the `()` brackets (appologies for not knowing all the correct terminology).

```
# Create a class objects and run them
strengthObject = strength()

savingThrowsObject = savingThrows(strengthObject)
```

From here I expected the variable to work when passed through, but when running the code and attempting to use the butttons, I was informed by an error messaeg in the terminal that

```
AttributeError: type object 'strength' has no attribute 'strengthValue'
```

Which confusd me as I believed I was on the right track.

Comment: `self.strengthObject.strengthValue.get()` it is, instead of `strength.strengthValue.get()`

Comment: As for the future, before asking a question it is recommended to look into [ask] and into [mre]. Also taking a look into PEP-8 Style Guide will do some good for you and for us, when examine your code.

Comment: @Thingamabobs - I'm terribly sorry for the problems I caused with my question, and I am deeply thankful for your swift reply.

In the future, I will follow the guides you have sent me, in order to not cause more difficulty for those who are trying to help.

Once again, thank you.

Comment: It's a common problem that prevents a lot of question from getting answers. You got yours, following the guidelines will help you next time.